How to re-price an existing fixed rate mortgage?
I want to know what the theoretical price of an existing fixed-rate mortgage is once interest rates change.  That is, at what price would one expect the bank to sell the mortgage to another institution based just the interest rate change?
Edit added:  If certain provisions of a mortgage make this too difficult, such as a pre-payment option, then please feel free to state a hypothetical assumption (i.e., a mortgage with no pre-payment option).  Or recharacterize it as a 30-year bond with flat fixed monthly payments of ever increasing principle and ever decreasing interest, such that the principle balance is $0 upon the 360th monthly bond payment. <end of edit 1>
My real example: I have a 30-year fixed rate mortgage at 3.25% with a remaining balance of 575000.00 and 18 more years of payments.  I want to know what the "value" of that mortgage is today under current interest rates of around 6.5%.
I know there are bond calculators that will determine the theoretical price of a bond with a remaining life and fixed rate once the prevailing rate has changed.  But I am not confident enough in my math and financial knowledge to use one of those calculators on an amortized loan like a mortgage.

Option pricing is very difficult, and very model dependent.  Here, you need to model possible evolutions of the entire interest rate curve.  And of course you have a strip of options, as (most) mortgages in the US can be repaid at the holder's option at any coupon payment.

I appreciate the input, but if you can calculate the theoretical FMV of a 3.25% bond in a market where customers can pay face value on a new 6.5% bond, then it seems like one should be able to calculate it on the mortgage.  I'm just not sure how to deal with the fact the interest payment changes every month on an amortized mortgage.  Even if assumptions need to be made (including no pre-payment will occur), I am still hoping to understand the theoretical re-pricing.  I don't think the "possible evolutions of the entire interst rate curve" is relevant to bond pricing, why would it be for this?

The problem is the optionality.  If the prevailing rate is sufficiently low (compared to the rate on the old mortgage), the homeowner can save money by pre-paying the old one and refinancing.  Since the option can be exercised in the future, you need to model the probability that rates will drop that low.  And, since this exercise is tricky (it depends on appraisals and the general economic health of the borrower) you need to model all of that as well.

@lulu I think you're misinterpreting. Nothing about options in here, nor about "how to price a mortgage where the rate might adjust".

Not to mention that the homeowner may exercise their option for non-rate related reasons.  If they move, for example, or if they acquire sufficient wealth to seek to eliminate debt.  In other countries the homeowner has other choices available.

@CalvinLin  The key feature of a mortgage is the prepayment option!  That's the most important thing about it.  If you remove that, the pricing exercise is straight forward, but then it isn't a mortgage.

I get that, but my read of OP's understanding, is that they are at a very basic level. $\quad$ I would start first with walking them through how to use a mortgage calculator that does all the required math, since they are "not confident enough in my math and financial knowledge". IE A 575K mortgage on 20 years (don't have 18 year option) at 3.25% is 3261 monthly payment. Conversely, a 510K mortgage (no down payment) on 20 years at 6.5% is 3223 (very similar monthly paymnet). So that's roughly the "price" of it now, at least when valuing via income stream.

@CalvinLin Thank you much but I do not want to know the difference in monthly payments, or anything else an online mortgage calculator can easily calculate.  If there is a calculator online that can calculate the theoretical market value of a fixed rate mortgage when the market interest rate has changed, please let me know and I will use it.  I want to know the price to buy/sell the mortgage in whole.  There are theoretical models for calculating option prices and bond prices and I was hoping to find one for mortgage pricing.

If you want a quick fix:  $3.5$ is so very, very low that it's not entirely unreasonable to say that it will never be refinanced.  Then you can price it as a fixed rate amortizing bond, and the usual models you mention will do just fine.  After all, it's very unlikely mortgage rates will drop to $2%$ or whatever, so the economic prepayment option is basically worthless in this particular case.

Should say, though, that the Japanese 30 year mortgage rate has frequently been below $1.5%$.

@lulu Thank you much for the suggestion.  However, I can find amortization calculators and bond calculators but nothing for amortizing bond calculator.

Ignoring all the modeling issues discussed in the comments, you can do a simple present value calculation to compare and get a rough idea. The amortization formula relates the present value PV of a sequence of payments PMT m times a year, compounded m times a year with an annual interest rate of r for t years.
$$PV = PMT \frac{1 - (1 + \frac{r}{m})^{-mt}}{\frac{r}{m}}$$
A present value of \$575,000 at 3.25% with 18 years of monthly payments, compounded monthly would be a payment of $$PMT = \$575,000 \frac{\left(\frac{0.0325}{12}\right)}{1 - (1 + \frac{0.0325}{12})^{-12\cdot 18}} = \$3,519.67$$
A fixed payment of \$3,519.67 for 18 years at a 6.5% interest rate would be worth $$PV = \$3,519.67 \frac{1 - (1 + \frac{0.065}{12})^{-12\cdot 18}}{\left(\frac{0.065}{12}\right)} = \$447,475.62$$
In other words, a lender looking to get a sequence of \$3,519.67 monthly payments for the next 18 years at the current rate would be looking to loan something like \$447,475 at 6.5%, instead of your current balance of \$575,000.

Perfect, thank you.  I vaguely remember that math but 20 years of using online calculators and I've forgotten these basic formulas.  Now that you've explained it, I think what I should have realized to do is to use the basic mortgage calculator to calculate the monthly payment, then change the interest rate, and brute force the "home price" until I converged on the same monthly payment.  I appreciate your help.

@MRMcGillicuddy That's essentially what I did in the comments, but I read your reply as "that's not what I want."

@CalvinLin  My bad.  Prior to reading user1497162's answer I was in a different headspace.  I misread your comment as saying: "IE A 575K mortgage on 20 years (don't have 18 year option) at 3.25% is 3261 monthly payment. Conversely, a 575K mortgage (no down payment) on 20 years at 6.5% is 3223 (very similar monthly paymnet)."  And I thought, not only do I not care what the higher monthly payment is, i don't even think that's right because 3.5 to 6.5 apy should cause a significant monthly payment increase. Had I noticed the 510k vs the misread 575k I might have understood your point.  Sorry.
